# Export to txt from VBA

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I'm having some trouble exporting Excel files to txt files through VBA. The programm goes fine and generates a bunch of txt files with the information I want. The problem is that when exported, the txt file shows the date format as American, while I want it European dd/mm/yyyy. This doesn't happen when I save the txt manually. Here it is the code I'm trying to save the txt:

```
    tmpFile = "C:\Users\z864451\Desktop\Prueba\AIMS\AIMS_" & Filename
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=tmpFile _
    , FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
```

I have also tried to export to csv and then convert to txt but the same problem with the date happens again.

Any idea of how can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: To confirm, you are seeing an output of 05/17/2016 and expecting 17/05/2016 (17th of May 2016). Can you add a little more detail on exactly what you are seeing and the value of the cell

Comment: That's it, I am expecting to get a date in dd/mm/yyyy, however the txt file is mm/dd/yyyy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to use current date.

Below should do it:

`tmpFile = "C:\Users\z864451\Desktop\Prueba\AIMS\AIMS_" & Format(Now, “dd/MM/yyyy”)`

[Source](https://blog.udemy.com/vba-format-date/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I realized the answer was just in changing the date format, when selecting the format there are two of them one is *14/03/2011 which is the one that was causing the problem, just changing it to 14/03/2001 solves the whole thing.

Thanks